# Failing ternary operator

Tags: c++, googletest, conditional-operator

I have this ternary operator which always returns true:

```
int waitingTime = 0;
int awayPeriodThreshold = 5;

bool myOperator= 0? (waitingTime < awayPeriodThreshold) : 1;
```

I am using it in GoogleTest EXPECT_EQ, to compare two booleans.

I have a program which is measuring time, the output is 0 when time does not reach given threshold (in this case 5 seconds) and 1 when it is greater or equal five seconds. This works correctly but when I try to use this:

```
//at the beginning
bool isHigherThanTimeThreshold = 0
EXPECT_EQ(isHigherThanTimeThreshold, myOperator) //Test fails
// after lets say 10 seconds, isLowerThanTimeThreshold changes to 1
EXPECT_EQ(isHigherThanTimeThreshold, myOperator) //Test passes
```

it always fail because myOperator is always true, even on the beginning when waiting time is 0 an awayPeriodThreshold is 5;

How can I fix this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Looks like you got the idea about ternary operator from Python? If that's true, I suggest you forget everything you learned from Python and learn C++ as if it was your first language. It will be much easier than trying to draw parallels between these two languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool myOperator= 0? (waitingTime < awayPeriodThreshold) : 1;
```

means

```
bool myOperator= 1;
```

because `0` is always treated as false.

Ternary operator in C++ means `condition ? value when true : value when false`.

Therefore, you should write like this:

```
int myOperator= (waitingTime < awayPeriodThreshold) ? 0 : 1;
```

Note that you should use `int` (or other integer types like `char`) to store integers.

You can write like

```
bool myOperator = !(waitingTime < awayPeriodThreshold);
```

or

```
bool myOperator = (waitingTime >= awayPeriodThreshold);
```

to just check the condition.

Comment: Thank you very much, I over-engineered it and did not realize that it can be this simple. The time limit for answer acceptance is not over yet but I will accept your answer soon, thank you once again.

Comment: @Mechatrnk Sorry, `bool myOperator = (waitingTime < awayPeriodThreshold);` in my previous answer will give opposite result from what is specified in the question. Fixed.

Comment: That last one can be written without (the redundant parentheses).